Modeling a high dimensional multicollinear data
I am trying to predict a Plant physiology trait (y) from hyper spectral reflectance data from 400 to 2400nm (X). So far i have done the following

Skew correction with Square root (sqrt) on y
Scaling on X using MinMaxScaler to a range (0,1)
Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation (RFECV) to choose atleast 22 features using Partial least squares regression (PLSR) as estimator.

EDIT: 1st Derivative of the spectral data using a Savitzky-Golay filter (window_length=20, polyorder=3) is used a X and not raw spectral data
Distribution of y after skew correction

I am getting the below results for Ridge Regression
Does the cluster in true vs pred means the model is biased? How should i interpret the residual plot? What can be done to improve the model?

Why do you think the skew needs to be corrected? Also, please spell out your acronyms and tell us what Y is

@PeterFlom The only reason to perform skew correction was that y had a positive skew of 0.45. Performing skew correction gave me 3% increase in R2 Score and lower MSE. Y is a plant physiology trait.

using a square root on Y will give you a lower mse without (necessarily) improving fit. did you compare MSE on the original Y scale not sqrt(Y). eg if error between y and y_pred is 4, then the error between sqrt(y) and sqrt(y_pred) is 2.

That's not really a reason. The dependent variable does not have to be normally distributed.

I do see clustering around the peak of distribution of y. Does that mean the model is getting biased to the peak of distribution. I have about 3k rows of data, i notice more clustering  when i have about 1.5k rows of data. Does that mean it is over fitting? Will more data points essentially get me better scores?

to add to @PeterFlom's comment, you should not be aiming to have normally distributed independent variable (at least for prediction), you should aim to have a close to linear relationship.
I would rather use all the wavelengths with L2 regularisation than rfecv.
Spectral data is exactly when you should not rescale each wavelength, I would argue. Since I assume that the absolute size is comparable between inputs (wavelengths) and meaningful.
ie rescale all wavelength amplitudes using the same common scaling (eg min/max of all wavelength amplitudes).
L2 regularisation encourages small effects to have small outputs. large amplitudes (which are less likely to be noise), will tend to have smaller coefficients and so will not be regularised. L2 regularisation also selects for correlated signals -preferring a number of small weights ( as does PLS): this is typically what you would want in a spectral analysis, wehre you would assume you have a correlated signal (across wavelengths) and independent noise)

The reason i used recursive feature elimination (rfecv) to choose features was because multiple papers that dealt with such data suggest using them due to the high dimensional multi-collinear nature of the data. One other important point i missed mentioning in the Q descirption is that, I am taking 1st Derivative of the spectral data usign a Savitzky-Golay filter. This is what is then fed into RFECV. I perfromed scaling and skew coorection due to  nature of dataset without which leads to  larger residuals associated with higher values (Heteroscedasticity).

for prediction, the only criterion you should be focussing on is test score. you will find people using lots of methods.  ridge regression (l2 regularisation) is also a method for high dimensional collinear data - in fact the most well regarded for such data.

Yes, the plot i attached in the question was on test data using Ridge regression. And i even tried it on Lasso and Elastic Net (all three models give comparable results)
